# How to do url rewrite in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

I have following url .

```
http://localhost/cantqpromo/companies/detail/company_name
```

I want this url to be shown as :

```
http://localhost/cantqpromo/company_name
```

Can anyone help me , how can I achieve this .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/cantqpromo/*', 
      array('controller' => 'YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME', 
            'action' => 'YOUR_ACTION_NAME'),
      array('pass' => array('companyName'))
      );
```

In YOUR_CONTROLLER

```
function YOUR_ACTION_NAME($companyName=null){

    }
```

Now take one example to explain above thing:

Lets say you have 3 company names,

```
1- ABC, 2- XYZ, 3- MNO
```

Now the url for above companies will be

```
http://localhost/cantqpromo/ABC
http://localhost/cantqpromo/XYZ
http://localhost/cantqpromo/MNO
```

And the above urls will get resolved in YOUR_ACTION_NAME as mentioned above, `$companyName will be ABC, XYZ and MNO` respectively. If anything else is coming in `$companyName` then show error page or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Actually this company name is dynamic , passes from view . Can you tell me how this can be passed to routes.php ?